# Accessing an ItemRenderer in a DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I have a data grid that has a checkbox item renderer in a cloumn to allow row selections:

**Main application:**

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="ir" itemRenderer="renderers.RowCheckbox" /> 
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Name" headerText="Name" /> 
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

**Item renderer:**

```
<-- RowCheckbox -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" horizontalAlign="center"> 
    <mx:CheckBox id="chk"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

How can I get a handle to the item renderer / checkbox so that I may determine which rows are checked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a word of advice: We had a similar problem in our application and we solved it by adding a "selected" property to the entities in the dataprovider of the datagrid. The selected property of the checkBox was then bound to the selected property of our entity. To know which ones were selected, we just looped over the entities in the dataprovider instead of the item renderers. After a lot of different approaches, this really was the best option.

If I remember correctly, the problem was that the itemrenderers did not remember the selected state correctly and the datagrid was completely messed up when you scrolled up and down. The wrong rows were selected after scrolling.

Another option would be to dispatch an event in the item renderer which bubbles up all the way to the control hosting the datagrid. You could then listen for these events and update your model to reflect the changes.

Comment: This raises an excellent point.  In my zeal it looks like I missed what the poster was really asking; indeed this seems like a sound way to go, because you're right, renderers are reused, and that reuse could have unintuitive and unintended consequences.  +1

Comment: We've used that approach as well and I'd agree it's probably the easiest.

Comment: This is probably the easiest and most elegant solution ( as It is completely compliant with OOP encapsulation rules) we have came up with.

Comment: This is a good way to go about it if you don't mind having other crap in your data. If you *do* want to go about it the hard way you can use the visibleData property on the DataGrid to parse which rows should be selected out of the currently visible rows. Then, when the datagrid is scrolled, re-evaluate which rows should be selected.

Comment: The itemRenderers must change themselves based on the data they are given to show.  This is because ItemRenderers are recycled.  If you change the data of what on the screen is the 4th ItemRenderer, you could actually be making changes to the 11th one instead.  In other words, you should not change the values of an ItemRenderer externally.  You must have each ItemRenderer react to changes by themselves. 

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar issues with the DataGrid and multiple item renderers and the reuse of item renderers when scrolling.  In order to access DataGrid item renderers I extended the DataGrid.  My first thought was to use the indicesToIndex() followed by indexToItemRenderer().  Unfortunately these methods didn't do what I expected so I added the indicesToItemRenderer() method:

package com.whatever.controls
{

```
import mx.controls.DataGrid;
import mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer;

public class CustomDataGrid extends DataGrid
{

    public function CustomDataGrid()
    {
        super();
    }

    public function indicesToItemRenderer(rowIndex:int, colIndex:int):IListItemRenderer
    {
        var firstItemIndex:int = verticalScrollPosition - offscreenExtraRowsTop;
        if (rowIndex < firstItemIndex ||
            rowIndex >= firstItemIndex + listItems.length
            )
        {
            return null;
        }

        return listItems[rowIndex - firstItemIndex][colIndex];
    }

}
```

To resolve the reused item renderers when scrolling issue, refer to this article:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html

It boils down to overriding the data setter and storing properties in data.  For example, I had one column using a CheckBox itemRenderer and another column using ComboBox.  For both I listen for the change event and store selected, selectedIndex, etc in data whenever properties change and override the data setter to set those properties:

```
        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                super.data = value;

                if (data.hasOwnProperty('selected') && data.selected)
                {
                    selected = data.selected;
                }
                else
                {
                    selected = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: FANTASTIC. The indicesToItemRenderer() function was exactly what I was looking for. I Can't believe there isn't something like that already on DataGridBase since ListBase's indexToItemRenderer() doesn't take into account columns! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `indexToItemRenderer()` method exposed by all subclasses of ListBase.

For example:

```
private function someFunction(index:int):void
{
    var rowCheckbox:RowCheckbox = dg.indexToItemRenderer(index) as RowCheckbox;
    trace(rowCheckbox.chk.selected.toString());
}
```

... where `index` represents the index of the DataGrid item whose "chk" property you want test.

Comment: I don't think this will work with multiple item renderers in diffrent columns, say I need the renderer in another column, how can I do that?

Comment: Good point, yes.  Christophe's answer is actually better; I've used the above approach on single-column, non-scrolling lists and had good results, but what you're really looking for is neither a property of the underlying data nor of the visible display objects, but rather something in the middle.

Comment: You could modify your above function to check both the row and column of the custom Renderer... someFunction(row:int,cell:int):void

Answer (score -1):

In the ItemRenderer, try putting Checkbox Component in a VBox..resolves the scrolling issue.